# Как вывести views в Drupal 7 c переключателем отражения материала?

Tags: php, drupal, hook, views

Давно мучает этот вопрос, есть представление например "каталог товаров", когда заходим на страницу `*/catalog`, то материалы открываются списком.

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на соответствующий значок (который сами вставим в нужное место) товары открылись плиткой.

Думаю, что можно подставить в адрес аргумент, например так: `*/catalog?big` (чтобы views все-таки понимал, что нужно выводить, если мы перешли по прямой ссылке), то есть по умолчанию в представлении выбран формат: «таблица > поля», если нажали на соответствующий заначек, и адрес принял вид типа: `*/catalog?big`, то представление должно выводиться в формате: «неформатированный список, готовая к выводу сущность».

Читал views API но пока безрезультатно, подскажите куда копать? Может быть есть  hook, который распечатает код представления, внедрившись в который можно будет поменять формат в зависимости от условий?

Сейчас знаю способ только с помощью js и css, но это неправильно настраивать стили, если при изменении формата, мне нужно в корне перестроить html структуру отражения типа материала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо сделать два нужных отображения. Установить модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/views_modes и настроить Фильтр (exposed filter) для отображения.

Дополнительно может пригодиться: http://gbyte.co/blog/simple-views-display-switch

Comment: минус в контекстной фильтрации по термину таксономии, так как словарик цепляется только на одно отражение, если этого не сделать, а настроить только в представлении, то у фильтроваться по термину будет только то которое прикреплено к словарю, а второе все время будет пустоту выводить. Идеально это когда в зависимости от условия формат будет меняться внутри одного отражения. 3 дня интенсивных поисков и сидения на формах, подсказали что нужно менять формат в самой теме представления. ......tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, надо создать дополнительное отображение в этом Views (не отдельный views, чтобы настройки были связаны) и переопределить у него формат вывода. И соответственно у него будет полностью другой URL. Способ простой и не требует никакого кодинга

Comment: никаких отдельных урлов, поисковикам это точно не понравится